# Using rvest with html_node to extract data from HTML table

Tags: r, html-table, rvest

I will start by saying that I am pretty new to R so please be gentle for this first timer.

I have created an R function to scrape HTML data from a webpage using the rvest library.  I have successfully used the html_node() function to extract some pieces of data from the page but I am having trouble with some data that is in an HTML table.

I have searched stackoverflow and other sites and found examples but none of them seem to work on this specific html. Below is the code that I am using:

```
    auctioninfo <- html_node(detailpg, "Auction") %>%
        html_text()

    print(auctioninfo)
```

- detailpg contains the full page HTML that contains the HTML below that contains the information I want to extract.
- "Auction" is the item from the table that I am trying to extract.

I have tried multiple identifiers for Auction (#Auction, .Auction, etc).

Below is the HTML code from the page that I am "scraping" for the data.

```
    <table class="bj-car-details-primary">
                        <tbody><tr class="row-fluid">
                <td class="" style="width: 40%;">Auction</td>
                <td class="" style="width: 60%;"><span id="Auction">Las Vegas 2016</span></td>
```

When I execute the code, I only receive NA in the auctioninfo vector.

[1] NA

I have also tried the html_table() function but that also has not worked as desired.

I am sure the answer is right in front of me but I have been stuck for quite a while and now I'm getting cross-eyed looking at it.

I need help identifying the CSS that I need to extract this data or help with the syntax for html_table() to get this specific piece of data.

Comment: use `html_node( "span")` instead

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I tried using "span" in place of "Auction" in the html_node line and didn't receive the Auction value of "Las Vegas 2016". I received the following:  
[1] "\r\n                \r\n                    Load More \r\n                \r\n

Comment: I'm still looking help on this issue if anyone has ideas.  Thanks.